# Would a DBMS be part of a database layer or DAL in an n-tier software architecture?

Tags: architecture

I have database layer, Data Access Layer then Business Logic Layer and so on, so I would like to know where the DBMS fits into this. Which layer would I put it in? And also, if someone could give an example of what I could put inside the business logic layer. Like what an example of a component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the DAL (Data Access Layer) is to decouple the higher-level tiers, such as the business later logic, from the DBMS, so that whenever you want to switch to a different database (i.e. different DBMS), only the DAL needs to be touched and nothing else. Therefore, the DBMS is not part of the DAL. Rather, the DAL depends on the DBMS.

For example, consider an e-commerce application. There is logic that decides whether some item or some user is eligible for free shipping. This shall be implemented in a module that belongs in the business logic layer. Internally, this check requires to fetch data about the item or the user from the database. This will be done by calling the DAL, which shall invoke the DBMS.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you another question? What do I put inside my business logic layer, in my diagram? I'm supposed to put some components but I don't know what would be an example of a component to put in my diagram. In my project, I need to draw this kind of software architecture diagram for a GP system where a patient can book online appointments with their GP doctor and they can also read their medical records etc. What would be an example of a component in the business logic layer? Like what title would I put inside a box inside my business logic layer as one example?

Comment: The names for components in the business logic layer should reflect the use-cases, i.e. what the system is intended to do, and not the concrete mechanisms that are involved in this process. For instance "AppointmentService" or "AppointmentBooker" or "AppointmentManager" would be appropriate. Also, "MedicalRecordAccessor".